# Trouble understanding topological groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, definition, topological-groups

I understand that a topological group is a group $G$ endowed with a topology $\tau$ on $G$ such that addition and inverse are continuous on $\tau$.

Now, the definition of continuity is that for all $U\in\tau$, $f^{-1}(U)\in\tau$. But in this case $+^{-1}(U)$ is a subset of $G\times G$ because the domain of $+$ is $G\times G$, and we endowed $G$ with a topology, not $G\times G$. So, where am I messing up?

Comment: $G\times G$ has the product topology

Comment: I love this question.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith why?

Comment: @AlexKruckman - I recognize an earnest desire to understand.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith That's a good reason!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The topology of $G\times G$ is the product topology, which is the topology of the unions of sets of the form $A\times B$, with $A,B\in\tau$.

Comment: And in brief, continuity of $+$ in general unfolds to: whenever $x+y \in U \in \tau$, there exist $V,W$ with $x \in V \in \tau, y \in W \in \tau$, and $V+W = \{ x' + y' \mid x'\in V, y' \in W \} \subseteq U$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Now I understand why some authors require the topology to be Hausdorff.